# Error with input when calling a function

Tags: matlab

I wrote a formula that computes the price of an fx call option that takes in 6 different arguments,

```
function [ result ] = fxcalloption( spotFX,di,fi,t,k,v )

d1=(log(spotFX/k)+(di-fi+0.5*(v^2))*t)/(v*sqrt(t));
d2=d1-v*sqrt(t);
result=spotFX*exp(-fi*t)*normcdf(d1)-k*exp(-di*t)*normcdf(d2);

end
```

and i also wrote a root solving algorithm which solves for the equation f=0 from range a-b within an allowable range and iterations

```
function [ result ] = illinois( f,a,b , yAcc,nlter)
```

now, i have the following codes,

```
syms x
store=0.105813579581848
f(x)=fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x,store )

g(x)=fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x-0.1,store )

illinois(f-g-300,0,1000,0.001,1000000)
```

However i have the following error instead,

```
Error using NaN
Trailing string input must be 'single' or 'double'.

Error in normcdf (line 60)
p = NaN(size(z),class(z));
```

i then tried to debug, by trying

```
f(x)=fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,x,2,store)
```

and i have the same error, so how can i bypass this?

I must make use of the illinois function

if for any interest, my illinois function is as follows:

```
function [ result ] = illinois( f,a,b , yAcc,nlter)

    if sign(f(a))==sign(f(b)) 
        %to satisify the initial condition of running the algorthim
        error('f(a) and f(b) have the same sign')
    end

for i=1:nlter;
    c=b-( (f(b)*(b-a))/(f(b)-f(a)));
    if abs(f(c))<yAcc;
        result=c;
        break %it satisifys the accuracy
    elseif i==nlter;
        error('max nlter reached')

    else
        if sign(f(c))==sign(f(a))
            a=c;
        else
            b=c;
        end
end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

`syms x` creates a symbolic variable `x` using the Symbolic Math Toolbox. But if I understand you correctly, you want to solve the equation numerically not symbollically. Instead, try to use function handles for the functions `f(x)`and `g(x)`. So your code could look like

```
store=0.105813579581848
f=@(x) fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x,store )
g=@(x) fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x-0.1,store )
illinois(@(x)(f(x)-g(x)-300),0,1000,0.001,1000000)
```

Comment: Hi, this is what i got

>> clear
>> syms x
store=0.105813579581848

store =

    0.1058

>> f(x)=@(x) fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x,store )
Error using sym/subsindex (line 1558)
Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

Comment: You don't need the `syms`command. Just run the four above lines (after issuing the `clear` command).

Comment: Error using erfc
Input must be real and full.

Error in normcdf (line 90)
p(todo) = 0.5 * erfc(-z ./ sqrt(2));

Error in fxcalloption (line 5)
result=spotFX*exp(-fi*t)*normcdf(d1)-k*exp(-di*t)*normcdf(d2);

Error in @(x)fxcalloption(1.2378,0.01,0.005,1,x-0.1,store)


Error in @(x)(f(x)-g(x)-300)


Error in illinois (line 3)
if sign(f(a))==sign(f(b))